# What are the differences between counting/calculation estimate and estimation by test-cases?

Tags: test-design, test-estimation

The counting/calculation estimate is based on counting countable indexes such as stories, usage scenarios, marketing requirements, web pages, technical requirements, functions.
Estimation by test cases as I understand based on counting test cases and categorizing them into groups such as easy, medium, hard. After these categories are created we assign average time to each category and multiply by the number of test cases. After that, we sum up the results.

If I understand everything correct, can estimation by test cases be included in the category of counting/calculation estimation? Because it looks like we just use test-case as an indexing value.

If we cannot include this estimation method into counting/calculation estimation category please explain why and explaining the differences between the two which have not been covered above.

Answer (score 1):

Given the definitions above, it seems reasonable to consider them as such.

However, it's good to remember that it cannot be used as an estimation for testing, because [test cases are not testing](https://www.satisfice.com/download/test-cases-are-not-testing). Using test cases counting is as good as an estimation for testing as counting the number of lines of code as an estimation for programming effort.

Comment: what's the point of your second paragraph? if anything JB's obsession with "testing" vs other things must come to an end (paraphrasing on his words), while technically correct it wastes time on meaningless arguments and creates distancing between condescending testers and the rest of the world

Answer (score -1):

Theory suggests below points that we can consider to do counting/calculation estimates

Domain Knowledge

1. Complexity of the application
2. Bug cycles for the project
3. Resources availability
4. Productivity variations
5. System environment and downtime

We can give estimates on the basis of testcases by below criteria:

Number of Test Cases = (Number of Function Points) × 1.2

Test Case Point Analysis measures the size of the test case, once you have the number of test cases, you can take productivity data from organizational database and arrive at the effort required for testing. The size of a test case is evaluated using following elements of test case

1. Complexity
2. Including checkpoint
3. Precondition
4. Data
5. Type of the test case